# Sorting a list with another list

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Is it possible to use the Java Collections sort method with a comparator to, as it sorts one list to also sort another list by the index of the original list so that the lists remains paired? Thanks.

Comment: Why not use same comparator to sort both lists separately?

Comment: @anubhava - If the two lists contain different data, but need their order to remain in sync, sorting each of them would produce a different order.

Comment: @anubhava because it won't help. After sorting, each element of list A changes its position. OP wants list B, being what's called a *parallel (to A) list*, had the same permutation. Not the same in a sense "sorted by the same comparator," no: same in a sense "if element *i* in list A goes to position *j*, then `B[i]` should go to B[j]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that with a Comparator. The solution to your problem is to build a third list that holds pairs of corresponding elements from the given lists. Then sort, and copy back to the original lists.

```
public class Pair<X,Y> {
  public final X x;
  public final Y y;

  public Pair(X x, Y y) {
    this.x = x; this.y = y;
  }
}

public static<X,Y> void sortTwoLists(List<X> xs, List<Y> ys, final Comparator<X> c) {
 if (xs.size() != ys.size()) 
   throw new RuntimeException("size mismatch");

 List<Pair<X,Y>> temp = new ArrayList<Pair<X,Y>>();

 for (int i = 0; i < xs.size(); ++i) 
   temp.add(new Pair<X,Y>(xs.get(i), ys.get(i)));

 Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<Pair<X,Y>>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Pair<X, Y> a, Pair<X, Y> b) {
    return c.compare(a.x, b.x);
  }
 });

 for(int i = 0; i < xs.size(); ++i) {
   xs.set(i, temp.get(i).x);
   ys.set(i, temp.get(i).y);
 }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that is roughly what I was getting at with the Sorted Map bit in my answer. +1 for an actual solution :)

Comment: Could you give an example of how to use this?

Answer (score 4):

No, because the comparator you would pass in to `sort` is only given a pair of entries at a time and simply gives back an order over those two elements. The comparator does not see the full list and so can't be used to effectively sort another list at the same time.

What it sounds like you are looking for is a sorted Map. The "second list" is then really just the values of the "key" in the first set. As the keys get reordered, the values will move along with them.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely write your own sort method to do this. I would have it take in the main list, a comparator, and the list to keep in "index-sync". From there, you just need to track where the elements are moving to as the first list gets sorted and move the elements in the 2nd list the same way.

Comment: @user1055696 Define a class `Pair<A, B>`; create a method `List<Pair<A, B>> combine(List<A>, List<B>)`; sort this list using a `Comparator<Pair<A, B>>`; create a method `Pair<List<A>, List<B>> split(List<Pair<A, B>>)` — and you're done. Not as if it was a preferred solution — I don't know your *real* goal, bur it's doable and readable.

Answer (score 0):

> Using comparator it is possible if we use ArrayList.

```
List<String> sortedList = Arrays.asList("Vin-1", "Vin-2","Vin", "Vin-5");
    Collections.sort(listToSort, new Comparator<T>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
            return Integer.compare(sortedList.indexOf(o1), sortedList.indexOf(o2));
        }
    });
```